# Angular JS - Getting [$resource:badcfg] error when unit testing $resource.get but is fine on controller

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs

Here's how I setup my Article resource:

```js
define(['services/index', 'services/Helpers'], function(services) {
  'use strict';

  services.factory('Article', ['$http', '$resource', 'AppConfig',
    function($http, $resource, AppConfig) {
      return $resource('http://' + AppConfig.APIHost + '/api/v1/articles/:id.:format', {id: '@id', format: 'json'});
    }
  ]);

});
```

It works fine when I use it in a controller. However on the unit test something like this:

```js
define(
  [
    'app',
    'services/Article',
    'mocks/articles'
  ],
  function() {
    describe('Service: Article', function () {

      // load the service's module
      beforeEach(module('ngResource', 'services', 'mocks'));
      beforeEach(function() {
        this.addMatchers({
          toEqualData: function(expected) {
            return angular.equals(this.actual, expected);
          }
        });
      });

      // instantiate service
      var Article, $httpBackend, injector, mockValues = {};

      beforeEach(inject(function(_Article_, _$injector_) {
        Article = _Article_;
        injector = _$injector_;

        $httpBackend  = injector.get('$httpBackend');
        mockValues.articlesMocksSet   = injector.get('articlesMocksSet');
        mockValues.articlesSuccessful = injector.get('articlesSuccessful');

        $httpBackend.whenGET(mockValues.articlesMocksSet.urlRegex)
          .respond(mockValues.articlesSuccessful);
      }));

      it('should be able to query from the API', function() {
        var articles;
        Article.query(function(results) {
          articles = results;
        });
        $httpBackend.flush();
        expect(articles).toEqualData(mockValues.articlesSuccessful);
      });

      // Pending sementara karena sepertinya ada bug di Angular v1.0.8
      it('should be able to query individual article by id', function() {
        mockValues.getArticleMocksSet   = injector.get('getArticleMocksSet');
        mockValues.getArticleSuccessful = injector.get('getArticleSuccessful');

        $httpBackend.whenGET(mockValues.getArticleMocksSet.urlRegex)
          .respond(mockValues.getArticleSuccessful);

        var article;
        Article.get({id: mockValues.getArticleMocksSet.id}, function(result) {
          article = result;
        });
        $httpBackend.flush();
        expect(article).toEqualData(mockValues.getArticleSuccessful);
      })
    });
  }
);
```

And I get this error:

```
Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration. Expected response to contain an object but got an array
  http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.0/$resource/badcfg?p0=object&p1=array
```

I am pretty sure the resource configuration is correct and verify that the JSON object is not an array. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the order of `$httpBackend` mock is wrong. Previously was:

```js
$httpBackend.whenGET(mockValues.articlesMocksSet.urlRegex)
  .respond(mockValues.articlesSuccessful);

$httpBackend.whenGET(mockValues.getArticleMocksSet.urlRegex)
  .respond(mockValues.getArticleSuccessful);
```

so `/api\/v1\/articles/` first and then `/api\/v1\/articles\/[\w|-]*/`. It should be the other way around. That's why I got an array response instead of object.